# Rails 4 Could not find the association has_many, through: relationship error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

Right. This simply refuses to work. Been at this for hours.

**album model**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :features, through: :join_table1
end
```

**features model**

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums, through: :join_table1
end
```

**join_table1 model**

```
class JoinTable1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :features
  belongs_to :albums
end
```

**join_table1 schema**

```
album_id | feature_id
```

**albums schema**

```
id | title | release_date | genre | artist_id | created_at | updated_at | price | image_path
```

**features schema**

```
id | feature | created_at | updated_at
```

Upon raking the test database, and running this integration test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class DataFlowTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "create new user" do
    album = albums(:one)
    feature = features(:one)
    album.features
  end
end
```

I get

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :join_table1 in model Album

Why is this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add `has_many :album_features` both to Album and Feature models (given that you rename JoinTable1 model to more meaningful AlbumFeature, and corresponding table would be `album_features`), as `:through` references association - your error is exactly about it.

Or you can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` so there will be no need to define special link model. But in that case you must name your table `albums_features`.

Comment: I don't think the naming convention of the join table matters with a has_many, through relationship.

Comment: You cannot have 2 models with name Feature, that is what matters.

Comment: Also, name of an activerecord model should correspond its table name.

Comment: if the naming convention mattered, would you name it album_features or features_album ? As @starkers mentioned it doesn't. I had the same problem, and adding has_many both to Album and Features in addition to through is the only relevant part of the answer.

Comment: @msanjay Yes, you're right, naming doesn't matter with has_many : through (although it does matter with has_and_belongs_to_many, afaik alphabetic order is used to decide what comes first in table name), this was addressed to the first version of question which had 2 errors in it. The question was updated, so I'll update the answer too, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Just define the models as follow

**album model**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :join_table1
  has_many :features, through: :join_table1
end
```

**features model**

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :join_table1
  has_many :albums, through: :join_table1
end
```

**join_table1 model**

```
class JoinTable1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :features
  belongs_to :albums
end
```

Answer (score 1):

happened to me as well.
made it work by adding the join table as has_many to both models. 
like this:
connection model:

```
module Alerts
  class AlertIncidentConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :incident
    belongs_to :alert
  end
end
```

alert model:

```
module Alerts
  class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :alert_incident_connections, class_name: 'Alerts::AlertIncidentConnection'
    has_many :incidents, through: :alert_incident_connections,class_name: 'Alerts::Incident', dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

incident model:

```
module Alerts
  class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base    
    has_many :alert_incident_connections, class_name: 'Alerts::AlertIncidentConnection'
    has_many :alerts, through: :alert_incident_connections,class_name: 'Alerts::Alert' ,dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

migration file:

```
class CreateTableAlertIncidentConnections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :alert_incident_connections do |t|
      t.references :alert, null: false, index: true
      t.references :incident, null: false, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

usage:

```
alert.incidents << incident
alert.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly like @mad_raz answered, but join table needs to have singulars for belongs_to, like this:

```
class JoinTable1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feature
  belongs_to :album
end
```

Complete associations tutorial https://kolosek.com/rails-join-table/